# Choosing between a deep discount bond and a loan with variable interest rate

Tags: loans, bonds, interest-rate, bond-coupons

I was wondering what kind of a method should be used to choose between a deep discount bond and a loan with variable interest. Since one option has a fixed rate, and the other has a variable interest rate, I am not sure whether and NPV analysis alone would help to determine the best option. Are there any other alternative methods I can use or is NPV perfectly fine?

Thank you!

Comment: ISTM that for the variable rate bond you'll have to perform **multiple** NPV calculations.

Comment: @RonJohn how do calculate multiple NPVs?

Comment: You break the problem into multiple pieces: calculate the NPV of each each interest rate for the time that it's in existence.